# Terraform "object required" for parameter value. Why?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following variable definition in terraform (for a blob storage blob_properties data, which is defined as dynamic in my terraform code:

```
variable "blob-properties" {
  type = map(object({
    cors-rules = list(object({
      allowed-headers = list(string)
      allowed-methods = list(string)
      exposed-headers = list(string)
      allowed-origins = list(string)
      max-age-in-seconds = number
    }))
  }))
  nullable = true
  default = null
}
```

This is the part of code where it is used:

```
dynamic "blob_properties" {
    for_each = var.blob-properties != null ? var.blob-properties : null
    content {
      dynamic "cors_rule" {
        for_each = blob_properties.value.cors-rules
        content {
          allowed_headers = cors_rule.value.allowed-headers
          allowed_origins = cors_rule.value.allowed-origins
          allowed_methods = cors_rule.value.allowed-methods
          exposed_headers = cors_rule.value.exposed-headers
          max_age_in_seconds = cors_rule.value.max-age-in-seconds
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This the value I am passing:

```
blob-properties = {
    cors-rules = [
      {
        allowed-headers = [ "*" ]
        allowed-methods = [ "GET","PROPERTIES" ]
        exposed-headers = [ "*" ]
        allowed-origins = [ "https://${local.b2c-storage-envs[count.index]}myurl.com" ]
        max-age-in-seconds = 200
      }
    ]
  }
```

I got the following error message:
`The given value is not suitable for module.login-storage-prod.var.blob-properties declared at ..\010-Common\Azure\azure-storage-account\variables.tf:61,1-27: element "cors-rules": object required.`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision Terraform "object required" for parameter value using the modules you mentioned and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

It seems the issue lies in the structure of your variable definition and the way you are passing values to it. The error "The given value is not suitable for module.login-storage-prod.var.blob-properties declared at ...: element "cors-rules": object required." suggests that there's a mismatch in expected and provided data types or structures for the `cors-rules` attribute in `blob-properties`.

The `cors-rules` within your `blob-properties` variable expects a list of objects. Each object within the list should match the structure defined in your variable declaration. Your value assignment seems to be structured correctly, so the error might be due to the way the variable is being referenced or a typo in the variable definition or value assignment.

I tried using an updated tfvars file which helps in achieving the requirement you're looking for.

**Note:** Remember always make sure the `blob_properties` variable should be a map of objects, each containing a list of objects for `cors_rules`.

**My terraform configuration:**

**Main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demorgvkstoacct"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"


  dynamic "blob_properties" {
    for_each = var.blob_properties != null ? var.blob_properties : {}
    content {
      dynamic "cors_rule" {
        for_each = blob_properties.value.cors_rules
        content {
          allowed_headers     = cors_rule.value.allowed_headers
          allowed_methods     = cors_rule.value.allowed_methods
          exposed_headers     = cors_rule.value.exposed_headers
          allowed_origins     = cors_rule.value.allowed_origins
          max_age_in_seconds  = cors_rule.value.max_age_in_seconds
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
variable "blob_properties" {
  type = map(object({
    cors_rules = list(object({
      allowed_headers    = list(string)
      allowed_methods    = list(string)
      exposed_headers    = list(string)
      allowed_origins    = list(string)
      max_age_in_seconds = number
    }))
  }))
  nullable = true
  default  = null
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
blob_properties = {
  some_key = {  # 'some_key' can be any name that represents this set of blob properties
    cors_rules = [
      {
        allowed_headers    = ["*"]
        allowed_methods    = ["GET", "POST"]
        exposed_headers    = ["*"]
        allowed_origins    = ["https://example.com"]
        max_age_in_seconds = 200
      }
      # You can add more cors rule objects here if needed
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Crap. I did not add the key into the passed variable data.